# How can we tell if an evaluation has corrupted or is still on-going properly?

Tags: kernel

[image]

I was trying to evaluate a NDSolveValue function of mathematica, but it is taking excessively long time (~30 min) now. I am not sure if I shall leave it alone or quit the kernel.

Is there a general way to tell if a kernel is functioning properly or stuck completely?

Comment: `Is there a general way to tell if a kernel is functioning properly or stuck completely?` one way could be (if you are on windows) is to look at task manager and see if the kernel.exe is changing its cpu and memory by noticeable amount as time passes, which indicates it is working OK and not stuck in a loop. If stuck in a loop, typically a process do not change CPU % and memory allocation much if any. You could also try on much smaller domain and time scale, and see if it finishes or not then. If it does, it most likely then it is still working when time and space is much larger.

Comment: Take a look at `EvaluationMonitor`.

Comment: No I am on a Mac. The problem is if I quit the kernel I will have to evaluate the entire notebook again and it would take a long long time to do so.

Comment: I am sure on the mac there is equivalent to task manager on windows?